# trouble with meteor connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, meteor

frustrated, desperate;  sorry if this is elsewhere, seem to be going in circles.  tried several solutions.  Basically the following gets an error "doesn't recognize MySQL. variable},  I have installed the MySQL package. 
How do I get the system to recognize the following?  I have used MySQL elsewhere with no problem.

```
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({.....
```

Comment: Can you post more code so we can have more context for what your doing? I assume you this is server only code?

Comment: Thanks for responding; probably should not have posted (was frustrated).  Gave up on solution of Meteor->Mysql  too many problems in both.  Learning on my own doesn't help though I gave it a lot of hours.  Tried working with MongoDb but underwelmed.     

Switched to Ruby ->rails (nodejs, etc) -> ThreeJS-> postgreSQL & neo4J;  data content: distributed (real) documents  and multiple relationships, but so far so could.